# How to return default state in redux toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am new to redux toolkit. here i am trying to return my previous state, after clearing the search input. Here is my reducers,

```
const dataSlice = createSlice({
  name: "data",
  initialState: {
    datas: [],
  },
  reducers: {
    search: (state, action) => {
      console.log(action.payload);
      if (action.payload) {
        state.datas = state.datas.filter((data) => {
          return data.mission_name.toLowerCase().includes(action.payload);
        });
      }
    },
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [dataFetch.pending]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    [dataFetch.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.datas = action.payload;
      state.loading = false;
    },
    [dataFetch.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.error = action.payload;
    },
  },
});
```

When I dispatch my search action, it returns my new state but when I clear the search field, it returns an empty array but I want to return my previous state. I am new to it. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should usually avoid saving filtered data in a reducer. Instead, keep the *original* data in the reducer, and then filter the data as needed *outside* the reducer (such as in a component).  That way you always have the original data available if needed.

As a side note, we recommend using the "builder callback" form of `extraReducers` as the default, rather than the "object" form:

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#the-extrareducers-builder-callback-notation

Comment: Thank you for this amazing answer. I am also curious to know that is there any way to filter the state values when needed and reset the previous value? as like the redux store where we can filter the state value and also set the default state.